# ¿Existe algun programa para crear temas wordpress sin saber programar?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

ando buscando un programa para crear temas en wordpress sin saber programar.Se programar mas o menos pero no puedo crear bien mis temas y si existiera algun programa me gustaria saberlo.

Gracias,Lord_Aguarras

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no es una pregunta de programación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido a SOe!

Esto es bastante aproximado a lo que ofrece WP Paintbrush

En principio se instala como un tema, pero una vez activado la cosa ya muestra todo su poder. En realidad es todo un framework que, partiendo de un diseño básico (ampliable), permite configurar un tema WordPress a gusto.

- info aquí: https://ayudawp.com/disenando-temas-wordpress-sin-saber-programacion/

Comment: el link esta obsoleto